# What is a Golden Word™?

Tags: pattern, knowledge, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a certain rule, then I call it a ***Golden Word™***.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Golden Words™ | Not Golden Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| GIANT | TINY |
| DUCK | GOOSE |
| CHARGE | RUSH |
| ANGEL | DEMON |
| DODGE | AVOID |
| KING | PEASANT |
| SHARK | SQUID |
| CLIP | CUT |
| GALAXY | PLANET |
| LAKE | OCEAN |

The CSV version:

```
Golden Words™, Not Golden Words™
GIANT, TINY
DUCK, GOOSE
CHARGE, RUSH
ANGEL, DEMON
DODGE, AVOID
KING, PEASANT
SHARK, SQUID
CLIP, CUT
GALAXY, PLANET
LAKE, OCEAN
```

These are not the only examples of ***Golden Words™***; more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYVi13xbJac) is the golden rule.

Comment: I was 100% expecting that to be the Lonely Island song.

Comment: @JohnClifford Well, the area is gray. But it's quite clear when you see the instant replay.

Comment: With a honey in the middle there's some leeway.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A word is a Golden Word if

> It is the name of a sports team from California.

Examples:

> Giant: San Francisco Giants
>  Duck: Anaheim Ducks*
>  Charge: San Diego Chargers
>  Angel: Anaheim Angels*
>  Dodge: LA Dodgers
>  King: Sacramento Kings
>  Shark: San Jose Sharks
>  Clip: LA Clippers
>  Galaxy: LA Galaxy*
>  Lake: LA Lakers*
>
>  *The starred ones are the ones I knew off the top of my head; the rest were found by n_palum

These words are called Golden Words because

> California is known as the Golden State.